# How to connect two virtual serial ports to read data from GPSFeed+?

Tags: linux, dart, connection, simulator, virtual-serial-port

Recently I've downloaded [gpsfeed+](https://gpsfeed.sourceforge.io) file, I set executable attribute and run it with (OS: **Manjaro**):

```
$ ./gpsfeed+_amd64\
```

I'm trying to list all ports connected through a Dart program (code [here](https://github.com/jpnurmi/dart_serial_port/blob/master/example/example.dart) by using package [dart_serial_port](https://github.com/jpnurmi/dart_serial_port)), but it lists nothing. I'm assuming it is because of virtual serial ports are not connected, but I don't know how to get this. There is a program like [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net) but it works on Windows only.

Any recommendation? Are there other simulators like `gpsfeed`?

**PS:** `gpsfeed+` is configured to work by using COM3 (protocol RS-232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Steps

- Download `gpsfeed+` from https://gpsfeed.sourceforge.io/
- Make executable the file downloaded:

```
$ chomod +x gpsfeed+_amd64
```

- Install `socat` package:

```
$ sudo pacman -S socat
```

- Create a pair of virtual serial ports (VSPs) with `socat`:

```
$ socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

- It displays virtual ports created, in this case: `/dev/pts/4` and `/dev/pts/5`. One port will be *transmitter* and the another one will be the *receiver*.
- Open `gpsfeed+` application:

```
$ ./gpsfeed+_amd64\
```

- In **Configuration** for `gpsfeed+` to do:

1. **Connection** >> check: *Serial*, and uncheck: *TCP, UDP, Http*
2. **Serial/IP** >> Port: */dev/pts/4* (*transmitter*), and Speed: *9600*

- Run simulator (button with a concentric circle as icon)
- Read data from */dev/pts/5* (*receiver*)

Python code (install `pyserial` package):

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/5', 9600)
iter = 5

while iter > 0:
  print(ser.readline().decode("utf-8"))
  iter -= 1
```

The very few existing packages for Dart (like `dart_serial_port`) do not work with virtual ports.